# Handling multiple radio buttons

Tags: angularjs

Here "idDefault" values are not changing. Please help me.

```
<div class="form-group" >
<label class="control-label">Select Colors : </label>
<div ng-repeat = "color in colorlist">
<input type="radio" name="color" ng-value="true" ng-model="color.idDefault"> 
{{color.colorName}} </input>
</div>
```

Colors : {{colorlist}}

and my JSON is

```
$scope.colorlist = [
{
  colorName:'Black',
  idDefault:true},
 {
  colorName:'Red',
  idDefault:false} ,
  { 
    colorName:'Bule',
  idDefault:false} ,
  {
  colorName:'Yellow',
  idDefault:false} ,
    ];
```

Initially black is selected. When selecting other colors, Black isDefault value not changing to false.

Comment: It is working fine for me.

Comment: If select Yellow, only Yellow isDefault value should be true. Black IsDefault must be change to false.

Comment: You want the changes to reflect in js file?

Comment: Yes It has to reflect

Comment: No, changes are applied only when the file is under execution. Once the execution is stopped, previous values are restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all as you are using color list for radio buttons , its the way for Checkbox list . But if you wanna use it like this only , you can do it by adding a `ng-change` in it like -

View Code-

```
<div class="form-group" >
 <label class="control-label">Select Colors : </label>
 <div ng-repeat = "color in colorlist">
  <input type="radio" name="color" ng-change="changed(color)" ng- value="true" ng-model="color.idDefault"/> 
 {{color.colorName}} 
</div>
 Colors : {{colorlist}}
```

and in controller add a method -

```
$scope.changed=function(color){
for(var i=0;i<$scope.colorlist.length;i++)
if($scope.colorlist[i].colorName!==color.colorName){
$scope.colorlist[i].idDefault=false;
}
}
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7k9okvw/)

hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are trying to use above is used for checkboxes where you can select multiple value but here you want only one color to be selected at time.

You can this as,

```
<div class="form-group" >
<label class="control-label">Select Colors : </label>
<div ng-repeat = "color in colorlist">
   <input type="radio" name="color" ng-value="color" ng-model="selectedColor"> 
   {{color.colorName}} 
   </input>
</div>
```

This way you can get the selected color in your contoller in `$scope.selectedColor` variable.

Comment: I need to return list to service